# detect same key value in list of dictionaries and merge them

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

I have a list, inside that list I have dictionaries with the same key value. The code should detect the duplicate `item_no` and should merge the dictionaries(add the price and count together). Python version is 3.5.

[image: code_capture]

```
[{'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 748}, 
 {'count': 3, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2244}, 
 {'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748}]
```

The end result should look like this:

```
[{'count': 4, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2992}, 
 {'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748}]
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Have you at least tried to loop over the dictionaries to create the result you describe? Post some code that shows your problem in solving this yourself.

Comment: I have added a perhaps a more efficient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [{'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 748}, 
     {'count': 3, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2244}, 
     {'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748}]

new_l = [{'count': sum(d['count'] for d in l if d['item_no']==item_no),
          'price': sum(d['price'] for d in l if d['item_no']==item_no),
          'item_no': item_no} 
         for item_no in set(i['item_no'] for i in l)]
```

Comment: Glad you liked it, its not the most efficient way but its more **pythonic** IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
from pprint import pprint

l = [{'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 748},
     {'count': 3, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2244},
     {'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748}]


items = dict()

for item in l:
    _id = item['item_no']
    if _id not in items:
        items[_id] = item
    else:
        items[_id]['count'] += item['count']
        items[_id]['price'] += item['price']

nl = list(items.values())

pprint(nl)
```

Output:

```
[{'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748},
 {'count': 4, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2992}]
```

Comment: BTW instead of `_id not in items.keys()` it's enough to write `_id not in items`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only iterates over `l` once, it also sorts `l` by count, although you can sort by whichever value you want it and it also re-assigns `l` instead of creating a new list:

```
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts):
    items = {}
    for dct in list_of_dicts:
        item_no = dct['item_no']
        if item_no in items:
            items[item_no]['count'] += dct['count']
            items[item_no]['price'] += dct['price']
        else:
            items[item_no] = dct
    return sorted(items.values(),key=lambda k: k['count'])

l = [{'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 748},
     {'count': 3, 'item_no': 'E-Y12-A6-301', 'price': 2244},
     {'count': 1, 'item_no': 'E-Y13-A3-301', 'price': 748}]  
l = merge_dicts(l)
```

If you want them sorted in descending order replace the return line with this one:

```
return sorted(items.values(),key=lambda k: k['count'],reverse=True)
```

If you want to neatly print out the dictionaries:

```
for dct in l:
    print ("Item No: "+dct['item_no'])
    print ("  Price: "+str(dct['price']))
    print ("  Count: "+str(dct['count']))
    print ("-"*50)
```

prints:

```
Item No: E-Y12-A6-301
  Price: 2992
  Count: 4
--------------------------------------------------
Item No: E-Y13-A3-301
  Price: 748
  Count: 1
--------------------------------------------------
```